# How would I access name created on the front end based on the values placed when registering?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I've created an API endpoint that successfully authenticates users upon logging in using their Email and Password on the front end side (React.js).  When they create an account, they must enter their `name`, `email` and `password`.  However, when they login - all they need to use is their `email` and `password` to login.

Upon logging in, I want it to say "Hey *name*".  How would I modify my endpoint so that even though user logs in with `email` and `password` only and I be able to access `name` so that I can use it in the front end?  How would I do that in my controller?  I've tried so many things but to no avail, I've a hit wall with this one.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create user
     *
     * @param  [string] name
     * @param  [string] email
     * @param  [string] password
     * @param  [string] password_confirmation
     * @return [string] message
     */
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
        ]);
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
        ], 201);
    }

    /**
     * Login user and create token
     *
     * @param  [string] email
     * @param  [string] password
     * @param  [boolean] remember_me
     * @return [string] access_token
     * @return [string] token_type
     * @return [string] expires_at
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Logout user (Revoke the token)
     *
     * @return [string] message
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully logged out'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User
     *
     * @return [json] user object
     */
    public function user(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json($request->user());
    }
}
```

Comment: After you successfully logged in you will see the response from API (Laravel). Check that from Network tab in your Developer tool. you will see all the data returned.

Comment: @Gabriel I did but it's only showing email, password and remember_me

Comment: in that case create one more api route and user controller, send request to that route and  return the user data, simple as that. NOTE: always put all sensitive API point inside authenticated middleware.

Comment: @Gabriel got it, thank you!

Comment: accept the answer given and close this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you successfully logged in you will see the response from API (Laravel). Check that from Network tab in your Developer tool. you will see all the data returned and utilize it as per required.

If data what you are looking for is missing from login returned data, create one more API route and UserController, send request to that route and return the user data, simple as that. 
NOTE: always put all sensitive API point inside authenticated middleware.